# Credit ON/OFF on Button click in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How to on or off credits with a button click in highcharts?
Can some 1 explain with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable/disable by show/hide functions, related with SVG object.

http://jsfiddle.net/N6b6H/1/

```
      $('#showhide').toggle(function () {
chart.credits.hide();       
             },function(){
chart.credits.show();               
             });
```

Comment: It's perfect with chart.credits.hide() or show(). I didn't know it. I was looking for in API Documentation but there was nothing about "credits" here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Here i created a jsfiddle in which bydefault the credit enable is false but onclick credit enables becomes true.

Try this:

```
 [http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/N6b6H/]
```

HTML is Like :

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px">

</div>

<button id="showhide"> Click Me </button>
```

Script is Like:

```
        $(function () {

$('#showhide').click(function(){
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: true
    },
              xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});
});

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});
});
```